# Dependency Injection in projects that have lots of classes that need to generate on the fly other classes

Tags: c#, java, oop, dependency-injection, factory

I am developing a kind a translator from language A to B (yeah, it kinda is like a compiler). A translation is generally from several different files and each one of them has the same 3 sections to translate. So, the way I did it, I kind of have it the following way:

[image]

When I instantiate a translator and give it some data, it will need to generate all the needed FileTranslator classes. As I shouldn't do the `new` in Translator, I should ask for a factory from above. The same happens in the Sections translators. This poses the problem that I'm forced to create a lot of boilerplate factories. Moreover, each one of the translators might need even more factories to generate some other classes they might want to use.

Am I thinking this the wrong way or is it just the way it is? I am not allowed to use any kind of DI/IoC framework in this project, btw.

### Edit:

I'm afraid I am not getting my message get sent across.

In this specific case, as my Translator class needs to be able to generate at any moment some FileTranslator, it would need a FileTranslatorFactory. I know I can have an IoC Container do the wiring for me, but the IoC Container in itself will not save me for the problem of having to code up the code of the FileTranslatorFactory itself. Am I right?

Now, the problem is that a FileTranslator will also have to be able to generate whenever it needs SectionATranslators, SectionBTranslators and SectionCTranslators (and do not think they are any similar because their names are -- they are totally different and have nothing to do with each other!). So I'd have to define factories for each one of them. So for such a simple 5 classes system, I'd need to create 4 (!!!) factories.

Being that I don't want my domain objects to depend on an IoC-Container and that I don't want to have a single factory for all the 4 kinds of objects that seem to need one, am I still missing something?

Comment: The most important thing for you is to code to interfaces, and make your generated code implement those interfaces.  That will make your life easier.

Answer (score 6):

The fact that there is a lot of boilerplate code involved in handcranking DI for class hierarchies like this is WHY the frameworks exist. Sorry, but unless you can get whoever decided on the no DI/IoC frameworks rule to change their mind, you are either going to be writing lots of boilerplate code, or you will end up writing a framework yourself.

*EDIT - with a completely fictitious framework, to keep this as agnostic as possible, but explaining how you can eliminate all but one call into the container in many scenarios.*

So, with an implementation of `Translator` like:

```
public class Translator
{
    private ITranslator translatorInstance;

    public Translator()
    {
        SomeContainer container = SomeContainer.CreateFromConfig(configFilePath);

        // this is the ONLY point we touch the container
        translatorInstance = container.GetMeA<ITranslator>();
    }

    // implementation
}
```

We can see that this works as a factory, and is the only class that needs to know about the container itself. An implementation of one concrete implementor of `ITranslator` could therefore be:

```
public class FileTranslator : ITranslator
{
    // private fields

    public FileTranslator(  ISectionATranslator sectionAtrans, 
                            ISectionBTranslator sectionBtrans, 
                            ISectionCTranslator sectionCtrans)
    {
        this.sectionAtrans = sectionAtrans;
        // etc
    }

    // implementation
}
```

Note here that `FileTranslator` knows nothing about which concrete classes actually implement the interfaces it depends on, nor does it need any sort of factory. In fact, the container will do this for you. There are several ways containers work this stuff out, one example is explicit config, something like:

```
<!-- absolutely fictitious configuration file, but similar to many frameworks -->
<ContainerConfig>
    <ObjectResolver interface="ITranslator">
        <ConcreteType type="FileTranslator">
            <ConstructorInjection>
                <Argument ordinal="0" type="SectionATranslator" />
                <Argument ordinal="1" type="SectionBTranslator" />
                <Argument ordinal="2" type="SectionCTranslator" />
            </ConstructorInjection>
        </ConcreteType>
    </ObjectResolver>
</ContainerConfig>
```

Many frameworks don't even need you to define the specific constructor arguments, you can just state that if you want a `ISectionATranslator` then return a `SectionATranslator` and it will automatically create these before calling the constructor.

Also note that some frameworks provide the option to define these type resolution rules in code, using fluent style APIs, and some allow you to define multiple potential ways of resolving a particular type, via some name (perhaps a `"Production"` implementation versus a `"UnitTest"` implementation).

Note that I have kept the above deliberately vague because I don't want to say which framework is best (and to be honest, I think it depends on your individual needs) - check elsewhere on StackOverflow for framework comparisons, and please try a few out (perhaps you can try some without telling your boss!). Hopefully, however, the above shows why an IoC container can make your code much cleaner by removing the need for layers upon layers of factory classes.

Comment: +1 Well put. OTOH, if you could make the decision to use a container, Castle Windsor's Typed Factory Facility addresses exactly this scenario.

Comment: I've been thinking about the this since yesterday and I still don't get it. Even using IoC Containers, I cannot avoid going through the hassle of having to define the factories myself. All that an IoC Container will do is do the auto-wiring for me. Or am I missing something? ty

Comment: You dont need factories - your container config just states "when I ask for a FileTranslator, please hand me one with SectionATranslator, SectionBtranslator,... configured". That's what you needed?

Comment: @Chris: but that is assuming my classes will know the ioc-container, isn't it? I'd like to keep my classes oblivious of the fact I am using an Ioc-Container at all (http://picocontainer.codehaus.org/container-dependency-antipattern.html). Maybe I am not fully getting what you mean?

Comment: Somewhere along the line you have to touch the container. Maybe you create a TranslatorFactory and that is the only place where it does a Container.GetMeA<ITranslator>() (or similar). The point is keeping the coupling to an absolute minimum

Comment: Generally I have a place where I do all the wiring (or let my ioc-container do it for me), yet it seems to me a big no to let my domain classes know about the container! http://picocontainer.codehaus.org/container-dependency-antipattern.html

Comment: Thats what I mean. eg you have just one factory class (not dozens) and in that one place, it calls into the container to ask it to build the hierarchy of related classes (as per your diag). None of those domain classes need to know about the container (or even each other, if related through interfaces)

Comment: Are you advocating to have one factory for all my kinds of needs for the whole system? I was thinking of having one factory for each different type of class (i.e, one factory for sectionA kind of class, one for B, etc. keep in mind that they are totally different and do not inherit from the same base class!).

Comment: @Chris: it's getting awkward having this discussion in the comments. I edited my original post.

Comment: Thanks - I will put a little example together which might hopefully explain better and update my answer - check back in an hour or so

Comment: To be honest, I don't find that idea any attractive. IMO, the composition root(that is, the place where all the wiring is done) should be outside the model. You still didn't show how can the Translator class create on the run as many FileTranslators as it wants without resorting to knowing the IoC. Yes, a class knowing the IOC can create as many objects of any kinds as it wishes. But then what you are actually doing is a disguised Service Locator! How would you do it if SectionATranslator would need to create an arbitrary number of object of type ABC on the run?

Comment: Have you read http://picocontainer.codehaus.org/container-dependency-antipattern.html ? What are your thoughts on it?